# Is it possible to commit the message from XA queue to non-XA queue in Camel?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-camel, ibm-mq, spring-jms

1) Receiving the message notification from an XA-queue which is defined as an endpoint in camel.
2) Now processing the message in a camel processor.
3) Result of processor is a list of XML messages set in its exchange.
4) Now Applying the splitter, and passing the individual messages to a queue which is non-XA.

Problem I am facing is: There is no error in the route, at-least I am not able to see any, but still Transaction manager is rolling back the message back to the original XA-queue.
While debugging I found out that processor is completing fine, but message is not getting committed in non-XA queue for some reason.

Note: IBM Websphere MQ is getting utilized here.

Tried searching online about it, but didn't find any resource.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Camel but with pure Spring or Spring Integration you would have to start a new transaction (`@Transactional` with propagation `REQUIRES_NEW`) with a non-XA transaction manager before sending to the queue.